# Tie multiple values to an event in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

I have a search form with several fields - 1 or all of them may be used. I also have an outbound link on the search results that trigger an event. What I am trying to do is determine how many of each search term is used in some way that resulted in a click to each of these outbound link events.

For example, let's say that I have the following searches, both which result in a click event on OutboundLink A

**Search 1**

- FirstName: John
- LastName: Smith
- ZipCode: 90210

**Search 2**

- LastName: Smith
- State: California

I would want something that aggregated the search terms that came before that outbound click event like this:

- John: 1
- Smith: 2
- 90210: 1
- California: 1

I can try to figure out a way to track this server-side, but I was hoping that I would be able to do this with Google Analytics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Event parameters are plain text, so you can set whatever you want. Just keep in mind you must follow a convention (defined by yourself) for what you concatenate and how you sort that data, this way your data will be consistent.

The way you want to view your data in `Events Report` can be accomplished only if you set every single search criteria into one of the parameters of an event and fire an event for each one. As I said before, you can set whatever you want in your parameters, but it's better to stay close to convention, so, maybe the parameter that best fits for this is `Label`. The simplest thing to do could be something like this:

```
_trackEvent('whatever-category', 'whatever-action', 'smith');
_trackEvent('whatever-category', 'whatever-action', 'john');
_trackEvent('whatever-category', 'whatever-action', '90210');
```

Asynchronous version:

```
_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'whatever-category', 'whatever-action', 'smith']);
```

Universal Analytics version:

```
ga('send', 'event', 'whatever-category', 'whatever-action', 'smith');
```

In your current implementation, supposing you are already using Category, Action, Label, maybe you have something like this:

```
_trackEvent('outboundlink', 'click', 'url-clicked-by-visitor');
```

Trying to add something else to any of these parameters will result in data split, and I think that's not a good idea.

Abusing a little bit of event parameters you could track every search criteria and relate it to the outbound link clicked:

```
_trackEvent('outboundlink', 'click', 'url-clicked-by-visitor');
_trackEvent('searchcriteria', 'url-clicked-by-visitor', 'smith');
_trackEvent('searchcriteria', 'url-clicked-by-visitor', 'john');
_trackEvent('searchcriteria', 'url-clicked-by-visitor', '90210');
```

Because URL's will be too many, I'll prefer to set them as `Action`, and set just one `Category` for keeping all of them grouped. Also you could set your search criteria as `Action` and URL as `Label`.

Parameter `Action` should indicate some kind of user interaction, but, I guess it's up to the webmaster set whatever makes sense. Anyway, this is not a best practice, but it'll work.